# Ubuntu Laptop Not Powering On

Tags: 22.04, power-management, battery

I have been using a Ubuntu-installed laptop for over two years now. However, recently, I have been experiencing an issue where the laptop does not turn on properly.

There has been no physical damage or any installations/removals made that could explain this issue.

Upon pressing the power button, the laptop either does not respond at all or briefly displays the Lenovo logo before shutting off. I have ensured that the laptop is fully charged and even tried using it with the power cord plugged in, but the issue persists.

I have checked for any disconnected wires or hardware issues but found everything to be in  order.

In an attempt to resolve the problem, I cleaned the laptop to remove any dust, which after that the laptop booted successfully. However, the issue reoccurred the next time I tried to turn on the laptop.

Comment: Not powering on or powering off hard like that is a hardware problem, not an Ubuntu problem.  This needs to be addressed by the hardware manufacturer's support team, not Ask Ubuntu.  It's possible something is broken on your system (battery, etc.) and needs replaced, which is beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Thomas Ward. I will send the laptop to get fixed and hopefully everything will be fine. It's strange that the laptop is having this issure, since I havn't dropped the laptop or anything.  Though the laptop was moveed around a lot, maybe that could be it

Comment: @Rinzwind I will try but the battry is internal and quite hard to take ou